# Unable to construct regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirement is something like this :

```
var actualstring = 'sales/salesorder/newOrder';
```

I'm writing a function which returns true if after `sales/`, there is a string and a forward slash (/). It has to return false if after `sales/`, there is just a string.

For example:

```
var actualstring = 'sales/salesorder/newOrder'; // should return true.  
var actualstring = 'sales/salesorder'; // should return false.  
var actualstring = 'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails'; // should return true.    
var actualstring = 'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails/View'; // should return true.   
var actualstring = 'sales/Invoice'; // should return false
```

So for this I have some regular expression like this :

```
var term = 'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails/View';
var re = new RegExp("^(/sales/[a-z0-9]{5,}/[a-z0-9]{5,}{/})$");
if (re.test(term)) {
    console.log("Valid");
} else {
    console.log("Invalid");
}
```

This clearly seems to be not working and completely lost in all the symbols.

Comment: You say backward slash and write a forward slash. Please format your code properly.

Comment: Regular expressions are great, frankly I don't always understand them, however.

Comment: An easy way to remember is forward slash has a positive slope (as defined in US algebra), backward slash has a negative slope (by the same definition)...

Comment: So the regex should be: 'sales/' followed by 1+ characters, followed by '/', followed by 0+ characters?

Comment: My apologies, I have rectified my question to forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you have described:

```js
var term = 'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails/View';
var re = new RegExp("^(sales\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}\/.*)$");
if (re.test(term)) {
  console.log("Valid");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid");
}
```

- Forward slack `/` needs to be escaped with a backslash. Like `\/`
- Your test string also contains capital letters, so `A-Z` needs to be checked too.
- There is a leading `/` in your your regEx but not in test string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Can you tell me what is this for : {5,} ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder `{5,}` matchs 5 or unlimited times. So, the 2nd string after 'sales/' needs to be at least 5 characters long. See more detailed explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/OJHysD/1

Comment: I dont need that validation , It can be of any no of characters. Once I remove it , the expression is not working. Also I need a "/" in front of sales. How can I modify the reg expression?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I refereed your own question, you were using that validation.  Replace `{5,}` with `+`. And add `\/` before sales. See https://regex101.com/r/OJHysD/2

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use

```
/^sales\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\//
```

where `^` = start of string, followed by `sales/`, followed by at least one alphanumeric character, up to any number of them, followed by a `/`

```js
var strings = ['sales/salesorder/newOrder', // should return true.  
'sales/salesorder', // should return false.  
'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails', // should return true.    
'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails/View', // should return true.   
'sales/Invoice']; // should return false  

console.log(strings.map(el => !!el.match(/^sales\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\//)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your regex into four groups

1. String should start with sales - `(^sales)`
2. Then there should be a forward slash - `(\/)`
3. Then there should be a word - `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`
4. Then there should be a forward slash - `(\/)`

So your complete regex will be

`(^sales)(\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/)`

Here is sample code

```js
let samples = ['sales/salesorder/newOrder',
'sales/salesorder',
'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails',
'sales/Invoice/InvoiceDetails/View',
'sales/Invoice']

let regex = /(^sales)(\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/)/

for(let sample of samples){
  console.log(regex.test(sample))
}
```